# No lithuanian or other letters allowed in Xamarin Entry

Tags: forms, xamarin, input, xamarin.forms, localization

I want to be able to enter not only lattin letters but symbols as well as lithuanian leters such as ąčęėįšųūž. On my xamarin forms entry `<Entry x:Name="pacientName"/>` its not allowed (no symbol displayed on keydown for foreign letters).

Maybe there are some settings. Or maybe I can make use of regex somehow?

Comment: What font is the entry displayed with? You might need to specify a font that you know contains printable characters for the desired unicode values.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thank you. I havent specifyed any font. Maybe default one doesnt accept my desired letters.

Comment: Do you mean that other foreign language characters cannot be displayed in the entry? You need to set the language of the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. How to set it? @JianweiSun-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you mean that other foreign language characters cannot be displayed in the entry? You need to set the language of the keyboard.

I thought it was because you didn't add the keyboard of the relevant language... Here is the [step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoVOr.jpg). For me, it works well.

My version:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2196" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.0" />
<!-- Android 11.0 - API 30 -->
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I am still unable to type letters from keyboard, but from virtual keyboard it works at least.